# How do I change a string to a decimal and set the value to 2 dp's in Python (3.6)

Tags: python, python-3.x, format, decimal, decimal-point

Apologies it appears my original explanation wasn't clear so I've updated the below as best I can.

I have created a dictionary from a list of fields and a fixed width file of data by slicing the data file up.

```
data_format_keys = {
            ("CURRENT-RATIO", 120, 127),
            ("ACID-TEST", 127, 134),
            ("NOTES", 134, 154 
            }
```

When printing this out I get the following...

```
Current Ratio = 1234
Acid Test = 5678
Notes = These are my notes
```

For the data in Current Ratio (1234) and Acid test (5678) I need to convert the strings to numerics and insert decimal points for use in calculations (these fields are from a mainframe file so are so need to be converted to the correct formats).

The expected output is...

```
Current Ratio = 12.34    #This is an integer/float
Acid Test = 5.678    #This is an integer/float
Notes = These are my notes    #This is still a string
```

I've created a list of fields that need to be converted from the original list but I'm struggling with how to apply the conversion

```
        for k,v in data_format_keys.items():
            if k in data_format_keys == headerdict[i[1]]:
                line = line.replace(k, v)
        fo.write(line)

print(headerdict)
```

Where headerdict is the initial dictionary created and data_format_keys is the list of fields for converting.

Any thoughts?
 Thanks

Comment: 1) There's a lot of unrelated code, it's not a minimal example. 2) Do you mean ... divide by 100?

Comment: `float(text)/100`?

Comment: I guess divide by 100 would work once the value is converted.  I was looking to insert the decimal point but this makes sense.  Thanks.

Comment: Not sure how to apply this to certain values in a dictionary though?

Comment: This in not clear at all. Please come up with a simply stated problem example. From what I understand, you have a dict in the form of `{("CURRENT-RATIO", 120, 127):val, ("ACID-TEST", 127, 134), val ..}` and you want to change the tuple keys to something else? Use a dict comprehension is the answer.

Comment: Once again: use a comprehension or loop to create what you want. Pseudo code: `dict([(k,v_for_float(v)) if k in ('Current Ratio', 'Acid Test') else (k,v) for k,v in key_value_source])` Come back with a more specific question if you cannot figure that out...

Comment: Thanks.  I get what this is doing and had tried something similar but I get the error ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#createlist from current output
thelist = [('Current Ratio', 1234), ('Acid Test', 5678), ('Notes', 'These are my notes') ]
#create dict with just notes
notes = dict([i for i in thelist if i[0] == "Notes"])
#create list without notes
thelist = [i for i in thelist if i[0] != "Notes"]
#create list of keys
thelist1 = [i[0] for i in thelist]
#create list of formatted numbers
thelist2 = [float(i[1]/100) for i in thelist]
#merge into dict
thelist = dict(zip(thelist1, thelist2))
#create empty dict
desired = {}
#update dict with previously created dicts
desired.update(thelist)
desired.update(notes)
print (desired)
```

Someone better at python may be able to write more efficient code, but this should be a good starting point.

Comment: Not sure how to apply this to certain values in a dictionary though?

Comment: `("CURRENT-RATIO", 120, 127)`

Do you want to see : **1201.27** or **1.20, 1.27** ?

Comment: {("CURRENT-RATIO", 120, 127), ("ACID-TEST", 127, 134)} This is splitting a fixed file so 120 is the start position, 127 is the end for the Current-Ratio. This is then taking a value from the file and creating the dictionary. The problem I have is that I then need to convert this value and the value for Acid-Test to a number for calculations but leave Notes as text

Comment: This seems a bit different from your original question. Please provide sample output of what you want to see.

Comment: Edit your question, provide expected output. So far your clarifications are confusing, remove any code that is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use formatted output if you like.

Here is an example:

```
#Inputs
meal_cost = float(input("Enter meal price: "))
drink_cost = float(input("Enter drinks cost: "))

#Calculation
total_cost = meal_cost + drink_cost

#Output
print("Your total bill is {:.2f} USD".format(total_cost))
```

Your output will look like this:

```
Enter meal price: 7.49
Enter drinks cost: 2.99
Your total bill is 10.48 USD
```

Let me know if this helped. :)

Comment: Not sure how to apply this to certain values in a dictionary though?